# Does medication to treat Obsessive-Compulsive Disorder reduce associated cognitive deficits?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, abnormal-psychology, depression

Some studies point to existence of cognitive deficits in OCD (it seems that these deficits are not comorbid but have the same neurological roots as OCD). Unfortunately I found no studies with positive effects of medication (SSRI etc.) on cognitive deficits/impairment in OCD patients. I found only one study about cognitive-behavioral therapy and improvement of cognitive deficits symptoms in OCD.

Is there any research that indicates medication used to treat OCD (such as SSRIs) can mitigate these cognitive deficits?

**Related articles:**

> - http://www.steveseay.com/ocd-cognitive-deficits-obsessive-compulsive-disorder
> - Fenger, M. M., Gade, A., Adams, K. H., Hansen, E. S., Bolwig, T. G., &
>     Knudsen, G. M. (2005). Cognitive deficits in obsessive-compulsive
>     disorder on tests of frontal lobe functions. Nordic journal of
>     psychiatry, 59(1), 39-44.
>     [PDF](http://web.psy.ku.dk/Anders_Gade/pdf/2005Fenger%20OCD.pdf)
> - Purcell, R., Maruff, P., Kyrios, M., & Pantelis, C. (1998).
>     Neuropsychological deficits in obsessive-compulsive disorder: a
>     comparison with unipolar depression, panic disorder, and normal
>     controls. Archives of General Psychiatry, 55(5), 415.
>     [LINK](http://archpsyc.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=203866)

Answer (score 2):

Look up [Jeffery Schwartz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffrey_M._Schwartz). He has done decades worth of scientific studies with hundreds of OCD patients. In [his book "You Are Not Your Brain"](http://www.youarenotyourbrain.com/) (worth a read) he mentions this bad brain wiring or cognitive deficits are the culprit behind the "Deceptive Brain Messages (OCD).

His studies show that self directed neuro-plasticity make the most corrections in brain wiring - and that the medicine can be an aid in the self directed steps. These self directed steps rely on the mind to alter the physical brain.